# How to limit Magento 2 Discount amount

Tags: magento2

I have to create a cart price rule according to this conditions,

*20% off is applicable to first-time customers

*20% off is capped at $100.

i don't have idea how to discount capped at $100. Please Help

Answer (score 0):

For this feature, we have to customize magento 2 using below steps.

- Create a cart price rule for your "first time" discount.
- Add an attribute to the customer object named something like "used_first_coupon". Defaults to 0/false.
- Add an event on customer creation that send the coupon code to the customer.
- Hook into the coupon applying code where you can check for the first time order or discount capped base on it you can manipulate the coupon validation.
- Add an event listener post-order that will mark the customers used_first_coupon attribute as true.